# PHP Database Search Validation

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a login page using PHP with a SQL database and i am trying to output different errors based on what the user enters. For example, if the user enters a correct "ID" but not the right password it will tell them the password is incorrect, but if they don't put a correct "ID" in it should tell them that the "ID/Password" doesn't exist. At the moment i have both of them working but my problem is that when you first open the page it shows the error message for the "ID/Password" being wrong which i assume has to do with nothing being entered yet. When something is entered though it does the error/correct messages correctly.

Here is just the part where the validation happens:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$login."'";
    $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);

    // A CORRECT ID WAS ENTERED
    if(pg_num_rows($results)) { 

        echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Incorrect Password was Entered</h2>"); 

    // A CORRECT ID WAS NOT ENTERED
    } else {

        echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Login/password not found in the database</h2>");

    }
```

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
 <?php 
    include "header.php";
    ?>

    <?php
    $id = "";
    $pass = "";

    $login = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $login = !empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';
    $password = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address, last_access 
            FROM users 
            WHERE id = '".$login."' AND password= '".$password."'";
    $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);

    if(pg_num_rows($results)) { 
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET last_access = '" .date("Y-m-d",time()). "' WHERE id = '" .$login. "'";    


    $first = pg_fetch_result($results, 0);
    $last = pg_fetch_result($results, 1);
    $email = pg_fetch_result($results, 2);
    $last_access = pg_fetch_result($results, 3);

    echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Welcome back $first $last</h2>");
    echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Our records show that your</h2>");
    echo("<h2 align=\"center\">email address is $email</h2>");
    echo("<h2 align=\"center\">and you last accessed our system: $last_access</h2>");
    echo("<br/>");

    } else {

        // WHERE THE VALIDATION HAPPENS
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$login."'";
        $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);

        // A CORRECT ID WAS ENTERED
        if(pg_num_rows($results)) { 

            echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Incorrect Password was Entered</h2>"); 

        // A CORRECT ID WAS NOT ENTERED
        } else {

            echo("<h2 align=\"center\">Login/password not found in the database</h2>");

        }

    }

    ?>

    <h2 align="center">Please log in</h2>
<p align="center" style="margin-top:-3px">Enter your login ID and password to connect to this system</p>
<form style="margin-top:-8px" name="Input" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table border="0" bgcolor="red" cellpadding="10" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<tr>
    <td style="border:hidden"><strong>Login ID</strong></td>
    <td style="border:hidden"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php if(pg_num_rows($results)) { echo $_POST['id'];} ?>" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border:hidden"><strong>Password</strong></td>
    <td style="border:hidden"><input type="password" name="pass" value="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<tr>
    <td style="border:hidden"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
    <td style="border:hidden"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

    <?php include "footer.php" ?>
```

Comment: When you first open the page your `$_POST` is __empty__

Comment: From a security standpoint, it's generally best not to even change the error message based on which field entry is incorrect -- otherwise you're giving an attacker a mechanism to enumerate the valid login IDs for your app

Comment: Check whether $_POST['id'] and $_POST['pass'] are set. If they're not, the whole validation should be skipped.